# T-SQL Select and count from different table?

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql

I have a table (`Threads`) containing a field (`id`). I would like to select every row from `Threads`, as well as the number of rows in the table `Posts` where the field `Posts.thread` is the same as `Threads.id`.

How can this be done in SQL?

(Something like this pseudo-SQL: `SELECT *, COUNT(* FROM Posts WHERE Posts.id=Threads.id) FROM Threads`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, COUNT(p.thread)
FROM Threads AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Posts AS p
        ON t.id = p.thread
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: Pipped to the post, this is the exact answer I was just about to give.

Comment: you should use left join, otherwise you don't get every row

Comment: second answer will have better performance that is why i vote it.

Answer (score 33):

Sure - something like this?

```
SELECT 
    t.ThreadID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Posts p WHERE p.ThreadID = t.ThreadID)
FROM
    dbo.Threads t
```

Comment: If you really do just want the ID (or just a few columns, not loads), then I would expect Waqas Raja's answer using join & group by to perform way better than this.

Comment: How can we sort on `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Posts p WHERE p.ThreadID = t.ThreadID)` column?