# How do I select items from one table such that a query in another table yields exactly one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: `Jobs` and `JobItems`:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs (
    [JobId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

Create TABLE JobItems(
    [ItemId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [JobId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
);
```

and for every row in `Jobs` there can be zero, one, or more rows in `JobItems` such that their `JobId` matches that of the row in `Jobs` which means that zero, one or more than one "job" contains that "item".

I need to select rows from `Jobs` such that there's exactly one row in `JobItems` with `JobId` matching that of the row from `Jobs` and tried code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667437/57428) (altered a bit):

```
SELECT JobId, (SELECT Count(ItemId) from JobItems WHERE
     JobItems.JobId=Jobs.JobId) from Jobs
```

and the problem is I now need to somehow say that I need only rows with exactly one match. So I tried to assign a shortcut to `Count(ItemId)`

```
SELECT JobId, (SELECT Count(ItemId) AS CountItemId from JobItems WHERE
     JobItems.JobId=Jobs.JobId) from Jobs WHERE CountItemId=1
```

but this makes SQL server unhappy - it says

> Invalid column name `CountItemId`

How do I have only items with exactly one match selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select *
from jobs i
where (select count(*) from jobitems ji where ji.jobid = j.jobid) = 1;
```

If however, table Jobs only contains all job IDs and nothing else, then you don't have to select from table Jobs at all:

```
select jobid
from jobitems 
group by jobid
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

A basic [**`GROUP BY HAVING`**](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/HQV8310312-Definition,-Use-of-Group-by-and-Having-Clause.html) clause will do it for you..

```
      SELECT Jobs.jobId
      FROM Jobs 
      INNER JOIN JobItems
         ON Jobs.JobId = JobItems.JobId
      GROUP BY Jobs.jobId
      HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT JobId, Count(ItemId) from JobItems group by JobId;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select jobid
From jobitems 
Group by jobid
Having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a temporary result set:

```
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT JobId
  FROM Jobs 
),
T2 AS (
  SELECT JobId, Count(ItemId) AS CountItemId 
  FROM JobItems 
  GROUP BY JobID
)

SELECT JobId, CountItemId
FROM T2
WHERE CountItemId = 1
```